# Pyomo's write function does not generate my ".nl" output

Tags: pyomo

No matter how much I tried to generate ".nl" output file for my model it keeps creating three empty files with ".row",".col", ".nl" suffixes.

My model does not have an objective function. So, I tried adding a dummy objective function but it did not help.

I should probably add that my model has complementarity constraints. Can that be the reason?

```
import numpy as np
from pyomo.environ import *
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.opt import ProblemFormat
from Dijkstra import ReturnPai 
from pyomo.mpec import *

NN=['do1','do2','1','2','3','4','5','dd']    
II=['1','2','3','4','5']
Des=['5']
DO=['do1','do2']
DDes=['dd']
KK=['HDV','AV']
HH=list(range(14))


LL=[('do1','1'),('do2','2'),('1','2'),('2','3'),('1','3'),('3','4'),('3','5'),('4','5'),('5','dd')]


NV_K={'HDV':6,'AV':6}     # The number of vehicles
NP_P={'do1':20,'do2':25}   # The number of passenger
Sigma_K={'HDV':0,'AV':1}
hlength=1

Teta_SD=15   # Unit cost for Solo drivers
Teta_RD=10   # Unit cost for ridesharing drivers
Teta_RP=5    # Unit cost for Ridesharing passengers
Teta_np=500  # Unit cost for waiting passengers
B_AV=3       # The total number of passenger in AVs 
B_HDV=4      # The total number of passenger in HDVs 
beta=1.28    # The rpoportion
eta=0.5      # Meeting elasticities 
A0=0.5       # Caliberation
epsilon2=pow(10,-3)


Tau_0={('do1','1'):0,('do2','2'):0,('1','2'):3,
       ('2','3'):1,('1','3'):4,('3','4'):2,('3','5'):2,('4','5'):1,('5','dd'):0}


ghead={'do1':0,'do2':0,'1':3,'2':1,'3':2,'4':1,'5':0,'dd':0}
gbeforehead={'do1':0,'do2':0,'1':0,'2':0,'3':1,'4':2,'5':1,'dd':0}
PAI ={'1':4,'2':3,'3':2,'4':1,'do1':4,'do2':5,'5':0,'dd':0}


gh={}
gomegah={}
for (i,j) in LL:
    gh[i,j]=Tau_0[i,j]/hlength
    gomegah[i,j]= 2*gh[i,j]
    


gh_min={}
for i in NN:
    if i not in DDes:
        gh_min[i] = 99999
        for j in II:
            if (i,j) in LL and Tau_0[i,j]/hlength < gh_min[i]:
                gh_min[i]=Tau_0[i,j]/hlength
                
for i in NN:
    if i not in DDes:
        if gh_min[i]==99999:
            gh_min[i]=0

        
        
gomegah_min={}
for j in NN:
    if j not in DO:
        gomegah_min[j] = 99999
        for i in NN:
            if (i,j) in LL and (2*Tau_0[i,j])/hlength < gomegah_min[j]:
                gomegah_min[j]=(2*Tau_0[i,j])/hlength                

for j in NN:
    if j not in DO:
        if  gomegah_min[j] == 99999:
            gomegah_min[j]=0
    
gg={}
for i in NN:
    if i not in DDes:
        gg[i]=len(HH)-gh_min[i]   
    


# Flow Capacity with 100% HDV and AV       
C_Full_0={('do1','1','HDV'):10000, ('do1','1','AV'):10000,
        ('do2','2','HDV'):10000, ('do2','2','AV'):10000,
        ('5','dd','HDV'):10000,  ('5','dd','AV'):10000,
        ('1','2','HDV'):15,('1','2','AV'):16,
        ('2','3','HDV'):12,('2','3','AV'):13,
        ('1','3','HDV'):11,('1','3','AV'):14,
        ('3','4','HDV'):9,('3','4','AV'):11,
        ('3','5','HDV'):5,('3','5','AV'):8,
        ('4','5','HDV'):7,('4','5','AV'):10}    


C_Full={}
C_Full_HDV={}
C_Full_AV={}
for i in NN:
    for j in NN:
        for k in KK:
            if (i,j) in LL:
                C_Full[i,j,k]= C_Full_0[i,j,k]*0.5 
                if k=='HDV':
                    C_Full_HDV[i,j]=C_Full[i,j,k]
                else:
                    C_Full_AV[i,j]=C_Full[i,j,k]

# Queue Storage Capacity
Q={}
for i in NN:
    for j in NN:
        if (i,j) in LL:
            for k in KK:
                Q[i,j,k]= C_Full[i,j,k]*(gh[i,j]+gomegah[i,j])



# PAI ={} 
# for i in np.setdiff1d(NN,DDes):
#     for j in DDes:
#         PAI[(i,j)] = ReturnPai(NN, LL,Tau_0, i, j)



np={}
nv={}
p_k1={}
p_solo={}
p_rs={}


for e in HH:
    for k in KK:
        if e==0:
            for i in DO:
                np[i,e] = NP_P[i]
                nv[k,e] = NV_K[k]
        else:
            for i in DO:
                np[i,e] = hlength*(-1*(p_solo[i,e-1]+(B_AV*sum(p_k1[i,j,'AV',e-1] for j in NN if (i,j) in LL))+B_HDV*p_rs[i,e-1] )) + np[i,e-1]
            if k=='AV':
                nv[k,e] = hlength*(-sum(p_k1[i,j,"AV",e-1] for i in DO for j in NN if (i,j) in LL) )+ nv[k,e-1]
            else:
                nv[k,e] = hlength*(-sum(p_solo[i,e-1]+p_rs[i,e-1] for i in DO for j in NN if (i,j) in LL))+ nv[k,e-1]
            
        # for i in DO:
        #     if np[i,e] <0:
        #         np[i,e]=0
        
        if nv[k,e]<0:
            nv[k,e]=0     
              
        for i in DO:          
            for j in NN:
                if (i,j) in LL:
                    p_k1[i,j,k,e]= A0*(.1*nv[k,e]+.1*np[i,e])
                   
                    if np[i,e] ==0 or nv[k,e]==0 or e>=7:
                        p_k1[i,j,k,e]= 0 
            if k == "HDV":
                p_rs[i,e]= sum(p_k1[i,j,k,e] for j in NN if (i,j) in LL)
            else:
                p_solo[i,e]=.1*(p_rs[i,e]+sum(p_k1[i,j,k,e] for j in NN  if (i,j) in LL))



#-------------Variables in  The Differential Complementarity Problem Model -----------------------
model = ConcreteModel(name='DCP')
ValidVarsIJH = [(i,j,e) for (i,j) in LL for e in HH]
ValidVarsIJKH = [(i,j,k,e) for (i,j) in LL for e in HH for k in KK]

model.Tau=Var(ValidVarsIJH, domain=NonNegativeReals, name= 'Tau', initialize=0)
for (i,j) in LL:
    for e in HH:
        model.Tau[i,j,e].setlb(Tau_0[i,j]) 


model.q_d=Var(ValidVarsIJH, domain=NonNegativeReals, name= 'q_d')
model.q_u=Var(ValidVarsIJH, domain=NonNegativeReals, name= 'q_u')
model.Q_cap=Var(ValidVarsIJH, domain=NonNegativeReals, name= 'Q_cap', initialize=0)
model.Gamma_Q=Var(ValidVarsIJH, domain=NonNegativeReals, name= 'Gamma_Q', initialize=0)
model.Gamma_C=Var(ValidVarsIJH, domain=NonNegativeReals, name= 'Gamma_C')
model.Delta=Var(ValidVarsIJH, domain=NonNegativeReals, name= 'Delta')
model.Deltabar=Var(ValidVarsIJH, domain=NonNegativeReals, name= 'Deltabar')
model.C=Var(ValidVarsIJH, domain=NonNegativeReals,name= 'C', initialize=0)

for (i,j) in LL:
    for e in HH:
       model.C[i,j,e].setlb(C_Full_HDV[i,j]) 
       model.C[i,j,e].setub(C_Full_AV[i,j]) 
       
model.rho=Var(ValidVarsIJH, domain=NonNegativeReals, bounds=(0,1), name= 'rho', initialize=0)
model.p=Var(ValidVarsIJH, domain=NonNegativeReals, name= 'p')
model.v=Var(ValidVarsIJH, domain=NonNegativeReals, name= 'v')
model.phi=Var(ValidVarsIJH, domain=NonNegativeReals, name='phi')
model.Bin=Var(ValidVarsIJH, domain=Binary, name='Bin',initialize=0)

model.pi_k=Var(NN,KK,HH, domain=NonNegativeReals,  name='pi_k' , initialize=0)


model.n=Var(ValidVarsIJKH,domain=NonNegativeReals, name='n')
model.p_k=Var(ValidVarsIJKH,domain=NonNegativeReals, name='p_k')
model.v_k=Var(ValidVarsIJKH,domain=NonNegativeReals, name='v_k')
model.q_dk=Var(ValidVarsIJKH,domain=NonNegativeReals, name='q_dk')
model.q_uk=Var(ValidVarsIJKH,domain=NonNegativeReals, name='q_uk')
# model.toll=Var(ValidVarsIJKH,domain=NonNegativeReals, name='toll')




for i in NN:
    for k in KK:
        for e in HH:
            if i in Des or i in DDes:
               model.pi_k[i,k,e].fix(0)
            else:
                model.pi_k[i,k,e]>=PAI[i]*(1-epsilon2) 
            if e>len(HH)-ghead[i]-1:
               model.pi_k[i,k,e].fix(PAI[i]) 


                

for (i,j) in LL:
    for k in KK:
        for e in HH:
            if e>len(HH)-gh[i,j]-1:
                model.p_k[i,j,k,e].fix(0)
                
            # if e<gh[i,j]:
            #     model.v_k[i,j,k,e].fix(0)
                
            if e<=gh[i,j]-1:
                model.Deltabar[i,j,e].fix(0)
                model.Delta[i,j,e].fix(0)
            
            if e<=gbeforehead[i]-1:
               model.Gamma_C[i,j,e].fix(0)
               model.Gamma_Q[i,j,e].fix(0)
               
            if e==len(HH)-1:
               model.q_dk[i,j,k,e].fix(0) 
            
            if j in DDes:
                model.Delta[i,j,e].fix(0)
                model.Deltabar[i,j,e].fix(0)
                model.Gamma_C[i,j,e].fix(0)
                model.Gamma_Q[i,j,e].fix(0)
                
            if i in DO:
               model.q_uk[i,j,k,e].fix(0) 
               model.Gamma_C[i,j,e].fix(0)
               model.Gamma_Q[i,j,e].fix(0)
            if i not in DO and e==0:
               model.q_dk[i,j,k,e].fix(0)

    

#---------The Differential Complementarity Model

expr=sum(model.n[k] for k in model.n.keys())

# model.Obj = Objective(expr = expr, sense=minimize,name='Obj')


model.matching_AV=ConstraintList(name="matching_AV")
model.matching_HDV=ConstraintList(name="matching_HDV")
model.FC_dummy=Constraint(pyo.Any)

for (i,j) in LL:
      if i in DO:
        for e in HH:
            model.matching_AV.add(expr=model.p_k[(i,j,"AV",e)]==p_k1[(i,j,"AV",e)])           
            model.matching_HDV.add(expr=model.p_k[(i,j,"HDV",e)]==p_solo[(i,e)]+p_rs[(i,e)])
        for k in KK:
            model.FC_dummy[i+','+j+','+k]=model.p_k[(i,j,k,0)]==model.v_k[(i,j,k,0)] 



model.N_Vehicles_link_0  = ConstraintList(name = 'N_Vehicles_link_0') 
model.N_Vehicles_link_e = ConstraintList(name = 'N_Vehicles_link_e') 

for (i,j) in LL:
    for e in HH:
        for k in KK:
            if e==0:
                model.N_Vehicles_link_0.add(expr=model.n[(i,j,k,e)] == hlength*(model.p_k[(i,j,k,e)]-model.v_k[(i,j,k,e)]))
            else:    
                model.N_Vehicles_link_e.add(expr=model.n[(i,j,k,e)]-model.n[(i,j,k,e-1)] == hlength*(model.p_k[(i,j,k,e)]-model.v_k[(i,j,k,e)]))



model.DownstreamQL0=ConstraintList(name = 'DownstreamQL0') 
model.DownstreamQL00=ConstraintList(name='DownstreamQL00')
model.DownstreamQL1_k=ConstraintList(name='DownstreamQL1_k')
model.DownstreamQL2_k=ConstraintList(name='DownstreamQL2_k')
model.DownstreamQL3_k=ConstraintList(name='DownstreamQL3_k')

for (i,j) in LL:
    for e in HH:
        for k in KK:
            if i in DO:
                if e==1:
                    model.DownstreamQL0.add(expr= model.q_dk[(i,j,k,e)]==hlength*(model.p_k[(i,j,k,e)]-model.v_k[(i,j,k,e)])) 
                elif e>=2:
                    model.DownstreamQL00.add(expr=model.q_dk[(i,j,k,e)]-model.q_dk[(i,j,k,e-1)]==hlength*(model.p_k[(i,j,k,e)]-model.v_k[(i,j,k,e)]) )
            else:
                if e==0:
                    model.DownstreamQL1_k.add(expr= model.q_dk[(i,j,k,e)]==hlength*(-model.v_k[(i,j,k,e)]))
                elif e<=gh[i,j]-1 and e>=1:
                    model.DownstreamQL2_k.add(expr= model.q_dk[(i,j,k,e)]-model.q_dk[(i,j,k,e-1)]==hlength*(-model.v_k[(i,j,k,e)]))
                else:
                    model.DownstreamQL3_k.add(expr= model.q_dk[(i,j,k,e)]-model.q_dk[(i,j,k,e-1)]==hlength*(model.p_k[(i,j,k,e-gh[(i,j)])]-model.v_k[(i,j,k,e)]) )


      

model.FC = ConstraintList(name = 'FC')
for i in NN:
    if not (i in DDes or i in DO):
        for e in HH:
              if e<=len(HH)-ghead[i]-1:
                for k in KK:
                    expr1 = sum(model.p_k[(i,j,k,e)] for j in NN if (i,j) in LL and e<=len(HH)-gh[(i,j)]-1)
                    expr2=sum(model.v_k[(j,i,k,e)] for j in NN if (j,i) in LL and e>=gh[(j,i)])
                    if not (type(expr1+expr2) == int or type(expr1+expr2)==float): 
                        model.FC.add(expr= expr1-expr2 == 0)
            
                        
model.Total_Inflow=ConstraintList(name = 'Total_Inflow') 
model.Total_Exitflow=ConstraintList(name = 'Total_Exitflow') 
for (i,j) in LL:
    for e in HH:
        model.Total_Inflow.add(expr=model.p[(i,j,e)]==sum(model.p_k[(i,j,k,e)] for k in KK))
        model.Total_Exitflow.add(expr=model.v[(i,j,e)]==sum(model.v_k[(i,j,k,e)] for k in KK))

 


model.UpstreamQL_0_k=ConstraintList(name='UpstreamQL_0_k')
model.UpstreamQL_1_k=ConstraintList(name='UpstreamQL_1_k')
model.UpstreamQL_2_k=Constraint(pyo.Any)

#model.UpstreamQL_2_k=ConstraintList(name='UpstreamQL_2_k')

for (i,j) in LL:
    if not i in DO:
        for k in KK:
            for e in HH:
                if e==0:
                    model.UpstreamQL_0_k.add(expr=model.q_uk[(i,j,k,e)]==hlength*model.p_k[(i,j,k,e)])
                elif e<=gomegah[i,j]-1 and e>=1:
                    model.UpstreamQL_1_k.add(expr=model.q_uk[(i,j,k,e)]-model.q_uk[(i,j,k,e-1)]==hlength*model.p_k[(i,j,k,e)])
                elif e>=gomegah[i,j]:
                    model.UpstreamQL_2_k['UpstreamQL_2_k('+i+','+j+','+k+','+str(e)+')']= model.q_uk[(i,j,k,e)]-model.q_uk[(i,j,k,e-1)]==hlength*(model.p_k[(i,j,k,e)]-model.v_k[i,j,k,e-gomegah[(i,j)]])



model.TotalDownstreamQL=ConstraintList(name='TotalDownstreamQL')
model.TotalUpstreamQL=ConstraintList(name='TotalUpstreamQL')

for (i,j) in LL:
    for e in HH:
        model.TotalDownstreamQL.add(expr=model.q_d[(i,j,e)]==sum(model.q_dk[(i,j,k,e)] for k in KK))
        model.TotalUpstreamQL.add(expr=model.q_u[(i,j,e)]==sum(model.q_uk[(i,j,k,e)] for k in KK))




model.ExitflowRate=ConstraintList(name='ExitflowRate')
for (i,j) in LL:
    if not j in DDes:
        for e in HH:
            if e>=gh[i,j]:
                model.ExitflowRate.add(expr=sum(model.v_k[(i,j,k,e)] for k in KK) == model.C[(i,j,e)]-model.phi[(i,j,e)]-model.Deltabar[(i,j,e)])



model.Comp_Downstream_LB=ComplementarityList(name='Comp_Downstream_LB')

for  (i,j) in LL:
    for e in HH:
      model.Comp_Downstream_LB.add(expr=complements(0<=model.phi[i,j,e],model.q_d[i,j,e]>=0))



model.Comp_delta=ComplementarityList(name='Comp_delta')
for (i,j) in LL:
    if not j in  DDes:
        for e in HH:
            if e>=gh[i,j]:
                model.Comp_delta.add(expr=complements( 0<=model.Delta[i,j,e],model.Delta[(i,j,e)] - model.Deltabar[(i,j,e)]>=0))
        




model.Comp_inflowwithheld_Q=ComplementarityList(name='Comp_inflowwithheld_Q')

for (i,j) in LL:
    if not i in DO:
        for e in HH:
            if e>=gbeforehead[(i)]:
                model.Comp_inflowwithheld_Q.add(expr=complements(0<=model.Gamma_C[i,j,e],(model.Q_cap[(i,j,e)]-hlength*(sum(model.p_k[(i,j,k,s)] for k in KK for s in HH  if s<=e and s<=gomegah[i,j]-1)+ sum(
                          model.p_k[(i,j,k,s)]-model.v_k[(i,j,k,s-gomegah[(i,j)])] for k in KK for s in HH  if s<=e and s>=gomegah[i,j]))>= 0)))


model.Comp_inflowwithheld_C=ComplementarityList(name='Comp_inflowwithheld_C')
for (i,j) in LL:
    if not i in DO or not j in DDes:
        for e in HH:
            if e>=gbeforehead[(i)]:
                model.Comp_inflowwithheld_C.add(expr=complements(0<=model.Gamma_C[i,j,e],model.C[i,j,e]-model.p[i,j,e]>=0))


model.Comp_inflowwithheld_T=ComplementarityList(name='Comp_inflowwithheld_T')


for (i,j) in LL:
    if not j in DDes:
        for e in HH:
            if e>=gh[i,j]:
                model.Comp_inflowwithheld_T.add(expr=complements(0<=model.v[(i,j,e)],sum(model.Gamma_Q[(j,m,e)]+model.Gamma_C[(j,m,e)] for m in NN if (j,m) in LL)-sum(model.Delta[(ii,j,e)] for ii in NN if (ii,j) in LL if ii<i) - model.Deltabar[(i,j,e)] >= 0))

#----------------nonlinear--------------
model.Rho1=ConstraintList(name='Rho1')
model.Rho2=ConstraintList(name='Rho2')

for (i,j) in LL:
    for e in HH:
        if e>=1:
            model.Rho1.add(expr=model.rho[(i,j,e)]<=model.n[(i,j,"AV",e)]/(model.n[(i,j,"HDV",e)]+model.n[(i,j,"AV",e)]+.0001)+.0001)
            model.Rho2.add(expr=model.rho[(i,j,e)]>=model.n[(i,j,"AV",e)]/(model.n[(i,j,"HDV",e)]+model.n[(i,j,"AV",e)]+.0001)-.0001)



model.LinkCap1=ConstraintList(name='LinkCap1')
model.LinkCap2=ConstraintList(name='LinkCap2')

for (i,j) in LL:
    for e in HH:
        model.LinkCap1.add(expr=model.C[(i,j,e)]  <= ((C_Full[(i,j,'HDV')]*C_Full[(i,j,'AV')])/(C_Full[(i,j,'AV')]+model.rho[(i,j,e)]*(C_Full[(i,j,'HDV')]-C_Full[(i,j,'AV')]))+.0001)+.0001)
        model.LinkCap2.add(expr=model.C[(i,j,e)]  >= ((C_Full[(i,j,'HDV')]*C_Full[(i,j,'AV')])/(C_Full[(i,j,'AV')]+model.rho[(i,j,e)]*(C_Full[(i,j,'HDV')]-C_Full[(i,j,'AV')]))+.0001)+.0001)
        



model.QueueCap_0=ConstraintList(name='QueueCap_0')
model.QueueCap_1=ConstraintList(name='QueueCap_1')
model.QueueCap_2=ConstraintList(name='QueueCap_2')
model.QueueCap_3=ConstraintList(name='QueueCap_3')
model.QueueCap_4=ConstraintList(name='QueueCap_4')

for (i,j) in LL:
    if not i in DO:
        for e in HH:
            model.QueueCap_0.add(expr=model.Q_cap[(i,j,e)]<=((model.n[(i,j,"AV",e)]+model.n[(i,j,"HDV",e)])*Q[(i,j,"HDV")])/(((1/beta)*model.n[(i,j,"AV",e)])+model.n[(i,j,"HDV",e)]+0.00001)+(1-model.Bin[(i,j,e)])*Q[(i,j,"AV")])
            model.QueueCap_1.add(expr=model.Q_cap[(i,j,e)]>=((model.n[(i,j,"AV",e)]+model.n[(i,j,"HDV",e)])*Q[(i,j,"HDV")])/(((1/beta)*model.n[(i,j,"AV",e)])+model.n[(i,j,"HDV",e)]+0.00001)+(1-model.Bin[(i,j,e)])*Q[(i,j,"AV")])

            model.QueueCap_2.add(expr= model.n[(i,j,"AV",e)]+model.n[(i,j,"HDV",e)]<=sum(NV_K[(k)] for k in KK)*model.Bin[(i,j,e)])
            model.QueueCap_3.add(expr=model.Q_cap[(i,j,e)]<=0.5*(Q[(i,j,"HDV")]+Q[(i,j,"AV")])+(model.Bin[(i,j,e)]*Q[(i,j,"AV")]))
            model.QueueCap_4.add(expr=model.Q_cap[(i,j,e)]>=0.5*(Q[(i,j,"HDV")]+Q[(i,j,"AV")])+(model.Bin[(i,j,e)]*Q[(i,j,"AV")]))

        
        


model.Tau_Cal=ConstraintList(name='Tau')
for (i,j) in LL:
    if not j in DDes:
        for e in HH:
            if e>=1 and e<=len(HH)-gh[i,j]-1:
                model.Tau_Cal.add(expr=model.Tau[(i,j,e)]== Tau_0[(i,j)]
                                +((model.q_d[(i,j,e+gh[(i,j)])]/model.C[(i,j,e)])*
                                              (1+((model.phi[(i,j,e+gh[(i,j)])]+model.Deltabar[(i,j,e+gh[(i,j)])])/(model.C[(i,j,e)])))))
 


model.Comp_Routechoice=ComplementarityList(name='Comp_Routechoice')


for (i,j) in LL:
    if not j in DDes or not i in DO:
        for e in HH:
            if e<=len(HH)-gh[i,j]-1:
                for k in KK:
                    model.Comp_Routechoice.add(expr=complements(0<=model.p_k[(i,j,k,e)],model.Tau[(i,j,e)]+ model.pi_k[(j,k, e+gh[(i,j)])]- model.pi_k[(i,k, e)]>= 0))



model.demandsatisfaction=ConstraintList(name='demandsatisfaction')

for k in KK:
    model.demandsatisfaction.add(expr=sum(model.p_k[(i,j,k,e)] for (i,j) in LL  for e in HH if i in DO )==sum(model.v_k[(m,ii,k,e)] for (m,ii) in LL for e in HH if ii in DDes ))

model.write('Test.nl',io_options = {"symbolic_solver_labels":True})
```

Comment: Could you include a minimal example that recreates the issue you're seeing? How are you trying to generate the nl file? How are you declaring the complementarity constraints? Are you working with an AbstractModel or a ConcreteModel?

Comment: I edited my question and put the whole code to make sure that I am not missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your model using the latest Pyomo release (6.5.0) I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The model ('DCP') contains the following active components that the NL writer does not know how to process:
    <class 'pyomo.mpec.complementarity.Complementarity'>:
```

followed by a list of all the complementarity components. You need to apply a transformation to your model to reformulate the complementarities to a form that is compatible with a standard optimization solver. Unfortunately, there isn't any documentation for `pyomo.mpec` in the online Pyomo documentation but you can apply a `pyomo.mpec` transformation to your model by adding the following line to your code just before you tell it to write the nl file:

```
TransformationFactory('mpec.nl').apply_to(model)
```

This particular transformation will convert your MPEC into a form suitable for the NL writer. The available mpec transformations can be found here: https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/tree/main/pyomo/mpec/plugins. The above example uses the transformation defined in `mpec4.py`